# Segfault when assigning AF_INET to the sin_family attribute of a sockaddr_in structure

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

Here's my problem:

I'm trying to fill a socket address struct with the appropriate information so that I can use it in a program the handles communication between a server and a client.  This is part of the server code. The problem is that it segfaults.  When I run `gdb`, it says that the seg fault occurs when I assign `AF_INET` to the `sin_family` attribute for the `servaddr` struct.

code:

```
servaddr->sin_family = (short)(AF_INET);
```

I can't seem to figure out why this occurs.

Here's the full code:

```
// Function Prototypes
struct sockaddr_in* getServerInfo(char[]);

int main()
{

    char hostname[MAXHOSTNAMELEN];
    struct sockaddr_in* servaddr = getServerInfo(hostname);

 return 0;
} // End main

struct sockaddr_in* getServerInfo(char hostname[])
{

    struct sockaddr_in* servaddr = malloc((size_t)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    gethostname(hostname, 32);
    struct hostent *hostptr;
    hostptr = gethostbyname(hostname);

    memset((void *) &servaddr, 0, (size_t)sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr->sin_family = (short)(AF_INET);
    memcpy((void *)& servaddr->sin_addr, (void *) hostptr->h_addr, hostptr->h_length);
    servaddr->sin_port = htons((u_short)8000);

    return servaddr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bug is here:

```
memset((void *) &servaddr, 0, (size_t)sizeof(servaddr));
```

Do this instead:

```
memset((void *) servaddr, 0, (size_t)sizeof(*servaddr));
```

Otherwise you're zeroing the pointer for servaddr, (i.e. turning it into NULL). This then explodes when you try and use it.

Similarly you'll need to change your memcpy call.

Comment: Agreed. Anyway, it would be more easy (and even more secure btw) using `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` to allocate **and** initialise the structure referred to by `servaddr`. The call to `memset()` would not be necessary then.